# Does declaring a class protected automatically make its members protected?

Tags: c#

If I have a public class and fail to provide an access modifier for one of its members then it is defaulted to private. I was wondering if the default access modifier (private) is ALWAYS the default regardless of the class' accessibility in which it is contained.

For example

```
public class Galaxy : Universe
{
    //This is private since no modifier was used
    void CreatePlanet()
    {
      //do stuff
    }
}

protected class Universe
{
    //access modifier is omitted (private or protected?)
    int GetGalaxyCountWithinDistance(Galaxy g, int LightYears)
    {
        int answer = some logic;
        return answer;
    }
}
```

Can I not do this?

```
{
    Galaxy MilkyWay = new Galaxy();
    int closestGalaxies = MilkyWay.GetGalaxyCountWithinDistance(MilkyWay, 100);
}
```

Or would I painstakingly have to declare every single member of my protected class, protected itself?

Comment: `protected Universe` - that doesn't compile.

Comment: He means `protected class Universe`.

Comment: In c# implied accessibility is always private.  Once I got used to it, I really appreciated that I didn't have the exact opposite of something like vb w/ an implied accessibility of public (in which I had to go mark them all as private, or worry that one might not have been marked)

Comment: Regardless of the access level of your class all member variables that don't have an explicit visibility get the default.

Comment: Yes, you have to "painstakingly" have to declare them all protected. And it would be a good thing if you "painstakingly" declared every private methods private too. By the way, I think that's a pretty strong code smell if you have so much methods that writing the simple accessibility parameter is a pain.

Comment: @Tejs - `public Class Galaxy : Universe` will not compile with `protected class Universe` - so sample is very strange.

Comment: Note that only inner classes can be `protected`. Trying to put that on a top-level class causes [a compiler error](http://ideone.com/2k2tsb).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short. The default is `private`. So yes you will need to explicitly state that the variables are `protected` regardless to the class' access modifier.